# Some problem with preloader on web page with JS

Tags: javascript, jquery, animation, preload

I am trying to create a simple preloader on web page but I have few mistakes.
JS code is not working.
This code should work before the web page is fully loaded and then disappear completely
Does someone know how to fix this problem or some another way or something else?
I would be grateful for any advice and any help.

```js
function preloader() {
    $(() =>{
        setInterval(() => {
            const p = ('.preloader');
            p.css('opacity', '0');
        }, 3000);
        setInterval(
            () => p.remove(),
            parseInt(p.css('--duration')) * 1000
        );
    });
}

preloader();
```

```css
body{
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    font-family: Verdana, sans-serif;
}
#loader-container{
    min-height: 1080px;
    min-width: 1920px;
    z-index: 999999;
    background-color: #000000;
    opacity: 1;
    transition: opacity .35s;
    -webkit-transition: opacity .35s;
    -moz-transition: opacity .35s;
    -o-transition: opacity .35s;
}

#load {
    position:absolute;
    width:1200px;
    height:36px;
    left:40%;
    top:40%;
    margin-left:-300px;
    overflow:visible;
    -webkit-user-select:none;
    -moz-user-select:none;
    -ms-user-select:none;
    user-select:none;
    cursor:default;
}

#load div {
    font-size: 90px;
    position:absolute;
    width:20px;
    height:36px;
    opacity:0;
    font-family:Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
    animation:move 2s linear infinite;
    -o-animation:move 2s linear infinite;
    -moz-animation:move 2s linear infinite;
    -webkit-animation:move 2s linear infinite;
    transform:rotate(180deg);
    -o-transform:rotate(180deg);
    -moz-transform:rotate(180deg);
    -webkit-transform:rotate(180deg);
    color:#35C4F0;
}

#load div:nth-child(2) {
    animation-delay:0.2s;
    -o-animation-delay:0.2s;
    -moz-animation-delay:0.2s;
    -webkit-animation-delay:0.2s;
}
#load div:nth-child(3) {
    animation-delay:0.4s;
    -o-animation-delay:0.4s;
    -moz-animation-delay:0.4s;
    -webkit-animation-delay:0.4s;
}
#load div:nth-child(4) {
    animation-delay:0.6s;
    -o-animation-delay:0.6s;
    -moz-animation-delay:0.6s;
    -webkit-animation-delay:0.6s;
}
#load div:nth-child(5) {
    animation-delay:0.8s;
    -o-animation-delay:0.8s;
    -moz-animation-delay:0.8s;
    -webkit-animation-delay:0.8s;
}
#load div:nth-child(6) {
    animation-delay:1s;
    -o-animation-delay:1s;
    -moz-animation-delay:1s;
    -webkit-animation-delay:1s;
}
#load div:nth-child(7) {
    animation-delay:1.2s;
    -o-animation-delay:1.2s;
    -moz-animation-delay:1.2s;
    -webkit-animation-delay:1.2s;
}

@keyframes move {
    0% {
        left:0;
        opacity:0;
    }
    35% {
        left: 41%;
        -moz-transform:rotate(0deg);
        -webkit-transform:rotate(0deg);
        -o-transform:rotate(0deg);
        transform:rotate(0deg);
        opacity:1;
    }
    65% {
        left:59%;
        -moz-transform:rotate(0deg);
        -webkit-transform:rotate(0deg);
        -o-transform:rotate(0deg);
        transform:rotate(0deg);
        opacity:1;
    }
    100% {
        left:100%;
        -moz-transform:rotate(-180deg);
        -webkit-transform:rotate(-180deg);
        -o-transform:rotate(-180deg);
        transform:rotate(-180deg);
        opacity:0;
    }
}

@-moz-keyframes move {
    0% {
        left:0;
        opacity:0;
    }
    35% {
        left:41%;
        -moz-transform:rotate(0deg);
        transform:rotate(0deg);
        opacity:1;
    }
    65% {
        left:59%;
        -moz-transform:rotate(0deg);
        transform:rotate(0deg);
        opacity:1;
    }
    100% {
        left:100%;
        -moz-transform:rotate(-180deg);
        transform:rotate(-180deg);
        opacity:0;
    }
}

@-webkit-keyframes move {
    0% {
        left:0;
        opacity:0;
    }
    35% {
        left:41%;
        -webkit-transform:rotate(0deg);
        transform:rotate(0deg);
        opacity:1;
    }
    65% {
        left:59%;
        -webkit-transform:rotate(0deg);
        transform:rotate(0deg);
        opacity:1;
    }
    100% {
        left:100%;
        -webkit-transform:rotate(-180deg);
        transform:rotate(-180deg);
        opacity:0;
    }
}

@-o-keyframes move {
    0% {
        left:0;
        opacity:0;
    }
    35% {
        left:41%;
        -o-transform:rotate(0deg);
        transform:rotate(0deg);
        opacity:1;
    }
    65% {
        left:59%;
        -o-transform:rotate(0deg);
        transform:rotate(0deg);
        opacity:1;
    }
    100% {
        left:100%;
        -o-transform:rotate(-180deg);
        transform:rotate(-180deg);
        opacity:0;
    }
}
```

```html
<div class="container preloader" id="loader-container">
    <div id="load">
        <div>G</div>
        <div>N</div>
        <div>I</div>
        <div>D</div>
        <div>A</div>
        <div>O</div>
        <div>L</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you included jQuery?
Do so, then something like this:

```
    $(() => {
        const p = $('.preloader');
        setInterval(() => {
            p.css('opacity', '0');
            setInterval(() => {
                p.remove();
            }, 350)
        }, 3000);        
    });
```